# Question about how initial conditions imply the function is even or odd

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Hi guys I a have a general question. I am reading a book [Hill's Equation](https://books.google.com/books?id=XwEMurjYXvYC&pg=PR2&lpg=PR2&dq=Hill%27s%20equation%20by%20Magnus%20and%20Winkler&source=bl&ots=dJf-3N6GJ9&sig=FSVIAlIfrnnkS53CT0xRZ2cYrfY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiuyof8i8_PAhVB6GMKHYTFD3EQ6AEIPTAF#v=onepage&q=Hill%27s%20equation%20by%20Magnus%20and%20Winkler&f=false)
By Wilhelm Magnus, Stanley Winkler and on page 9, there is quick conclusion saying that. We have initial conditions

$y_1(0)=1$, $y_1'(0)=0$, $y_2(0)=0$, $y_2'(0)=1$. In the book they claim that if $y_1(t)$ and $y_2(t)$ are linearly independent solutions then $y_1(t)$ has to be even and $y_2(t)$ has to bee odd because of the initial conditions. My question is this obvious, as in I see how $y_1(-0)=y_1(0) $ and $-y_2(0)=y_2(-0)$, but I am not sure how they conclude it is true in general. Can someone shine some light at me?

Comment: You also need some time symmetry in the differential equation for this conclusion.

Comment: That is correct, I had some time to think. In general it is not true, but it is true for examples as the Hill's equation and we can justify it, by uniqueness.